# Ubuntu 14.10 gets stuck in a loop and keeps trying to re-mount smartphones

Tags: mount, nautilus, android, phone, smartphone

I am running Ubuntu 14.10 on a Lenovo Ideapad y410p. I have a pretty fresh install, less than a week old. Fully up to date.

At first I was just having this issue with Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 4, I would connect it to the computer via USB and start a file transfer or just leave it charging (doesn't matter whether or not I interact with it on the computer) and then it would disconnect on its own for some reason and then Ubuntu would try to re-mount it automatically and come up with an error pop-up saying it was unable to mount and a nautilus window would pop open trying to show the phone's internal storage. I guess Ubuntu is locked out or something but then it keeps trying to mount and keeps opening Nautilus windows and gets stuck in a loop unless I disconnect the USB.

I have been using the Ubuntu phone for a couple of months now and noticed this every once in a while. I thought it was the phone and that the problem had progressed as now it happens most times the phone is plugged into the laptop. I have also reformatted the laptop since first experiencing this issue and still experience it on a fresh Ubuntu 14.10 install.

I figured the problem was related to Ubuntu touch until my friend plugged in his Nexus 5 to charge last night and it started doing the same thing. It was fine for a bit and we didn't pay attention to it, then an hour or two later there there are dozens of nautilus windows open along with dozens of unable to mount pop ups.

I am not sure how to recreate the issue. It seems to happen randomly. I don't get any kind of error reports from the system, the unable to mount pop up is the same that you get when you stick a cd/dvd into a drive (from my reading on the internet it seems that almost everyone gets that popup in Ubuntu for the last couple years or something).

Right now I am just borrowing different people's smart phones and leaving them connected via USB to see if I can find a definitive way to recreate the problem. I would appreciate any suggestions anyone can offer.

Thanks for reading (I have tried googling the issue but have not been able to find anything).

Answer (score 0):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1160847:

```
The workaround I am using:

    Add this rule to /lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules

    #skip Nexus 4/10 for UT debug ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="4ee2", GOTO="libmtp_rules_end"

    Add a new file to /etc/udev/rules.d called 99-android.rules
    # enable access to nexus devices SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTR{idProduct}=="4ee2", MODE="0666"

    The usb devices get mode 0664 by default so adb will require root without this.

    sudo udevadm control --reload-rules sudo service udev restart
```